# Bluetooth does not work in Android x86 on VirtualBox

Tags: android, bluetooth, x86, virtualbox

I've installed Android x86 on VirtualBox, configured LAN settings and now I can use virtual machine instead of native emulator.

But still have an issue: I cannot turn on Bluetooth from menu. When I start BluetoothChat app, it just says "Turning on bluetooth..." and does nothing.

I suppose that probably I must configure VirtualBox or/and configure Android from command line, but have no idea what changes should be done.

Comment: Did you install the bluetooth driver of VirtualBox ? (i don't know if there is one, but it's my first tough).

Comment: I have installed VirtualBox Extension Pack.

Comment: This could be an issue with Android x86. If you are making an App for android (which would suggest why you're posting here on SO) it's best to use a real device for Android development which are now relatively inexpensive.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a USB Device Filter for your bluetooth device.

In virtual box, open settings, usb, then add filter. I hope this helps.

Comment: My Bluetooth is embedded (not USB).