# Bluetooth does not turn on VM virtual Box

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have Android X-86 installed on Virtual Box as  Virtual machine on my Windows 7. I am using Bluetooth dongle to access the Bluetooth on my VM. But I cannot turn on Bluetooth from menu. When I start Bluetooth app, it just says

```
Turning on Bluetooth...
```

and does nothing.It was working fine till the last time I used it but it stopped working suddenly.I have created VM using the following steps:

Set the type of guest OS as Linux instead of Other.
After creating the virtual machine, set the network adapter to 'Bridged'.
Start the VM and select '`Live CD VESA`' at boot.
Now you  find out the ip of this VM. Go to terminal in VM (use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> & <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to toggle) and use the `netcfg` command to find this.
Now  open a command prompt and go to your android install folder (on host). This is usually `C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools`>.
Type `adb` connect IP_ADDRESS
Plug in  USB Bluetooth dongle.
In VirtualBox screen, go to Devices>USB devices. Select  dongle.

Moreover I have found similar questions however nothing has helped yet
[Bluetooth does not work in Android x86 on VirtualBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415989/bluetooth-does-not-work-in-android-x86-on-virtualbox)
[USB bluetooth in Ubuntu 12.04 on Virtual Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10513790/usb-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-12-04-on-virtual-box)
Any ideas how can I use blue tooth dongle  on Vm would be really appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Successfully verified on:

Ubuntu: 16.04
Virtualbox: 5.0.24
Android x86: 4.4-r5, 5.1-rc1, 6.0-rc1*
Bluetooth USB Dongle Tested:

```
PASSES: Cambridge Silicon Radio CSR8510 A10 [8891]
 FAILS: Broadcom BCM20702A0 [0112]
```

To be able to do the following:

```
Android -> Settings -> Bluetooth -> On
```

You need to physically attach the Bluetooth USB dongle to the Host and virtually attach it to the VirtualMachine **before** starting it up the VirtualMachine.

***NOTE:** For Android 6.0-rc1, you can virtually attach the bluetooth USB dongle (and do a Android settings bluetooth enable) **after** boot up.

```
Virtualbox -> AndroidVitrualMachine -> Settings -> USB -> USB+ (Button icon with the balloon help that says - Add new filter with all fields set to the values of the selected USB device attached to the Host PC.)
```

I have verified this which included running the nRF Master Control Panel Android app and scanning for Bluetooth LE devices on the AndroidVirtualMachine.

Comment: Did you manage also run LE advertising on Android x86 ? For me `advertiser = bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeAdvertiser();` always returns null, although I know that the dongle itself can advertise (tested using Windows UWP sample application from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement

Comment: I tried Android-x86 6.0 Marshmallow (R3) with CSR8510 A10 and VirtualBox 6.
Done VM reset after ensuring adapter was connected.
Still can't get it working with Android x86.
I wonder how did you manage to succeed and have you tried more recent versions of Android/Virtual Box
And if there are other adapters that have any success report rate

Answer (score 0):

When you start up the VM, under Devices in the VirtualBox window that opens, ensure that under USB Devices there is a checkmark next to your bluetooth dongle device.

If it is not checked, and warns you that the device is in use already when you try to check it, unplug the dongle and plug it back in while the VM is still on the initial blue boot-up screen. *This must be done before the Android has booted up, or it will not work.*